# Getting the value in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem in getting all of the values from the `Total` column and display it in the grand total field, but it doesn't show anything. Please help I am new to jquery. I am using this kind of script.
[image]
I have a snippet [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jeffigy/2aLcr1qk/53/).

```
<script>
  $(function() {

      $('.total').mask('#,###.##',{reverse : true});

      var grand_total = function() {
          var sum=0;
          $('.total').each(function(){
              var num = $(this).val().replace(',','');

              if(num != 0) {
                  sum +=parseFloat(num);
              }    
          });
          $('#grand_total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
      }
       $('.total').keyup(function(){
          grand_total();
       });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This should work fine, please add a small demo for this which we can use to debug the issue.

Comment: There's no obvious issues in the code you've provided; so there must be some other issue - we can't help with that other issue as we can only go on what's provided. Add a snippet (there's a button when you edit the question) to provide a [mcve] will certainly help. The process of creating that snippet can frequently help you find the problem (eg if there's a typo in one of the IDs)

Comment: I have a snippet [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jeffigy/2aLcr1qk/53/) @palaѕн

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the demo you have shared: [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jeffigy/2aLcr1qk/53/)

There are a few issues in your code:

1. There is no element in your code having class `.total`. I am assuming the last column with header name as "Total" needs to have this class.
2. Next, you are calling `grand_total()` function on keyup event on `.total` class elements, but as no element exists with this class thus grand total field is not showing anything.
3. Also, "Total" column elements are `readonly`, so anyways `keyup` event will be never fired.

To resolve these issues, first add `.total` class to all the elements in "Total" column and then add `grand_total()` function inside all keyup events for classes `.amount1`, `.amount2` and so on.. so that when any of the keyup event is fired grand total will be auto-calculated.

Here is the updated demo with all the above changes: [Working Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sn63h7du/)